# WordPress RSS feed shows wrong lastBuildDate

Tags: wordpress, rss

I am having some troubles with the `lastBuildDate` of my wordpress rss feed.
It shows an older (!) date, not the latest one. 
I already deactivated all caching plugins without success. The updated date is from an older post, but I couldn´t figure out why it is using the date of exactly this post. (Newer posts are included in the feed!)

Also I printed the last modified date directly on the production server in the admin panel to verify that it is delivering the correct date.

```
<?php  echo get_lastpostmodified( 'GMT' ) ?>
```

And this showed the correct date of the last modification.

You can see it here in this feed: https://www.iamgreen.at/blog/feed/

Anyone an idea why the feed shows an older date?

Comment: Is it cached..?

Comment: I disabled my caching plugin, so I don´t think so. Also the difference between the lastBuildDate and the latest date is more than a year, so I don´t think that it would be cached that long.